# Implicit conversion gets too eager with an implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to define a type safe equal matcher with an implicit formatter:

```
trait Formatter[T] {
  def format(t : T) : String
}

implicit val StringFormatter : Formatter[String] = new Formatter[String] { def format(s: String) = s"'$s'" }
implicit def AnyFormatter[T] : Formatter[T] = new Formatter[T] { def format(t : T) = t.toString }

class MatcherOps[T : Formatter]( t : T) {
  def must_==(other : T) {
    if( t != other ) println( implicitly[Formatter[T]].format(other) ) else println("OK")
  }
} 

implicit def ToMatcherOps[T : Formatter](t : T) = new MatcherOps[T](t)
```

The following works as expected:

```
"ha" must_== "ho"
```

it is compiled (`scalac -Xprint:typer`) into

```
$anon.this.ToMatcherOps[String]("ha")($anon.this.StringFormatter).must_==("ho");
```

But then I would expect this to not compile:

```
List(1,2) must_== Set(1,2)
```

And instead it compiles (`scalac -Xprint:typer`) to

```
$anon.this.ToMatcherOps[Object]($anon.this.ToMatcherOps[List[Int]](immutable.this.List.apply[Int](1, 2))($anon.this.AnyFormatter[List[Int]]))($anon.this.AnyFormatter[Object]).must_==(scala.this.Predef.Set.apply[Int](1, 2))
```

As you can see ToMatcherOps is called twice!

If I take the implicit formatter out of the way:

```
implicit def ToMatcherOps[T](t : T) = new MatcherOps[T](t)
```

Then compiling fails as expected:

```
error: type mismatch;
  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
  required: List[Int]
List(1,2) must_== Set(1,2)
                     ^
```

But of course `ToMatcherOps` is unable to provide a sensible `Formatter` (`scalac -Xprint:typer`):

```
implicit private def ToMatcherOps[T >: Nothing <: Any](t: T): this.MatcherOps[T] = new this.MatcherOps[T](t)($anon.this.AnyFormatter[T]);
```

Any idea how to work around this?
Thanks

Comment: You say it works if you remove the formatter implicit, what's the problem then?

Comment: Well then I don't get formatting. I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I came up with. Moving the implicit formatter parameter from the `MatherOps` class to it's methods.

```
package testpkg

trait Formatter[T] {
  def format(x: T): String
}

class MatcherOps[T](x : T) {
  def must_==(y: T)(implicit z: Formatter[T]) {
    if(x != y)
      println(z.format(y))
    else
      println("OK")
  }
}

object Test {
  implicit def ToMatcherOps[T](x: T) = new MatcherOps[T](x)

  implicit val StringFormatter = new Formatter[String] {
    def format(x: String) = "StringFormatter"
  }

  implicit val ListOfIntFormatter = new Formatter[List[Int]] {
    def format(x: List[Int]) = "ListOfIntFormatter"
  }

  implicit def AnyFormatter[T] = new Formatter[T] {
    def format(x: T) = "AnyFormatter"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    List(1,2) must_== List(1,2,3) // ListOfIntFormatter
    "string" must_== "another string" // StringFormatter
    1 must_== 2 // AnyFormatter
    1 must_== false // type mismatch
  }
}
```